# Error:java: release version 5 not supported

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, junit

I have a maven project in IntelliJ IDEA;
When I run the test using `mvn test` everything is fine, but when I use
the green arrow on IntelliJ IDEA I got this error: `Error:java: release version 5 not supported`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to: File->Project structure->Project and configure Project SDK to 1.8

Answer (score 2):

It is a [common error in IntelliJ](https://dev.to/techgirl1908/intellij-error-java-release-version-5-not-supported-376).

Try adding

```
   <properties> 
      <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source> 
      <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target> 
   </properties>
```

to your POM file.

Or:

- update Java Compiler
- update SDK version